# Selenium: Indivudually is working but unable to run code

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to get freight rates for 17424 pairs from here https://www.freightquote.com/. Firstly, I sign up the site and then I filled the requested information. My aim is to get lowest freight rate for each pair. If I run my code indivudually, it is working. However, when I run my all code, I have some issues that I could not understand the problems. I see such as "IndentationError: unexpected indent". Could it be possible to have IP problems ? or since I run my codes many times, could it be a problem that this website do not allow me to get the freigh rates because they have limit ? Below, you can find my codes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\b\Desktop\Webscraping\ZipCode.xlsx')
liste = df['zip'].tolist()
liste = liste[:2]


def find_rate(loc_a,loc_b):


PATH = r'C:\Users\b\Desktop\Webscraping\chromedriver.exe'
s= Service(PATH )
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)


link = "https://www.freightquote.com/"
driver.get(link)

sleep(2)

driver.maximize_window()
sleep(2)



 #Sign in:

 driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//img[@src="/en-US/-/media/Freightquote/Images/SearchNavIcons/icon-login.svg" ]').click()

 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username-field-modal"]'))).send_keys("NAME")

 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="password-field"]'))).send_keys("Password")

 driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = '//input[@type="submit"]')[0].click()

 driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = '//a[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg text-center" ]')[0].click()


#scroll down the cursor slowly
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, total_height, 5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))

######shipping from########

#Choose "Business"
driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = '//input[@name="locationType" and @id="Commercial"]')[0].click()



#click Accept
#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='truste-consent-button']"))).click()

element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@class="rbt-input-main form-control rbt-input"]')
element = element[0]
#element.send_keys(liste[0])
element.send_keys(loc_a)

sleep(2)
#Select the first option from autocomplete
element.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#scroll down the cursor slowly
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, 500, 5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))

#click right arrrow
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="ns-icon ns-solo ns-next"]'))).click()

#scroll down the cursor slowly
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, 500, 5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))


#Choose Lift Gate:
driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@name="liftGate" and @type="checkbox"]')[0].click()
sleep(2)
#click right arrrow one more time
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="ns-icon ns-solo ns-next"]'))).click()

#scroll down the cursor slowly
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, 500, 5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))

#click right arrrow one more time
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="ns-icon ns-solo ns-next"]'))).click()

######shipping to########

#Choose "Residential"
driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@name="locationType" and @id="Residential"]')[0].click()



#click Accept
#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='truste-consent-button']"))).click()

element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@class="rbt-input-main form-control rbt-input"]')
element = element[0]
sleep(2)
#element.send_keys(liste[0])


element.send_keys(loc_b)

sleep(2)
#Select the first option from autocomplete
element.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


 #scroll down the cursor slowly
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, 600, 5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))

#click right arrrow
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="ns-icon ns-solo ns-next"]'))).click()
#scroll down the cursor slowly
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, 700, 5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))

#click right arrrow
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="ns-icon ns-solo ns-next"]'))).click()

#item
element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@class="form-control"]')
element = element[0]
element.send_keys('Manufacturing goods')





#Packaging Type
select = Select(driver.find_elements(by=By.NAME, value="items[0].packageType")[0])
select.select_by_value('Pallet (48"x40")')

#Height and number of pallets
sleep(1)
element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@name="items[0].height"]')
element = element[0]
element.send_keys("72")

element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@name="items[0].weight"]')
element = element[0]
element.send_keys("2987")

sleep(1)

#scroll down the cursor slowly
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, total_height, 5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))
   
#click right arrrow one more time
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="ns-icon ns-solo ns-next"]'))).click()

#scroll down the cursor slowly
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, total_height, 5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))

#click right arrrow one more time
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="ns-icon ns-solo ns-next"]'))).click()

#get the lowest rate
WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-e2e-id='lowest-rate']")))
element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//h2[@class="emphasis-lg bold"]')
temp_freight = element[0].text
driver.close()
return temp_freight
```

Answer (score -1):

In Python, the code blocks are defined by their indentation.

Any extra indentation out of place (i.e., without `if`, `while` and other such constructs) will throw an `IndentationError`. Thus, within the same block of code, you must maintain the same amount of indentation. You can further refer [this](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html).

In your current code, you have extra space before     `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))` and that is throwing up the error.